# Can I use in-memory Entity Framework 6.2.0 or if there any approach to do it

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, in-memory-database

I want to use in-Memory entity framework  , could you help me guys

I can't find a way to use In memory db @ entity framework 6.2.0

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/

Comment: @Zakos - that is for EF Core. The OP specifies 6.2, that is the orther branch.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, there is an in-memory provider for EF6 available: https://entityframework-effort.net/

Comment: @Christian please provide a link or similar backing up your statement, why is is deprecated?

Comment: @CristianGiagante: there's nothing wrong with Effort so, yes, please consider adding additional resources to support your claim. Regards